# Would calling Prepare on subsequent loops hurt, help, or make no difference?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

With this code, which is inside a foreach block:

```
if (!First)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Dept.AccountID;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = Dept.AccountName;
    // should this call cmd.Prepare() too?
}

if (First)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@account_id", Dept.AccountID);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",Dept.AccountName); 
    cmd.Prepare();
    First = false;
}
```

...I added the comment at the end of the "not first" conditon.

Should Prepare() be called each time, or does the call to Prepare() when First is true suffice for each subsequent loop?

Comment: Did you time it with and without? Was one faster than the other?

Comment: Yes, "with" takes two shakes of a lamb's tail, and "without" takes three swishes of an agitated bobcat's stumpy tail. Or, to put it more succinctly: No. And you are implying that I should, and that would be the answer to my question, but it's not about that to me - I'm sure the time difference would not be noticed by anybdoy. I'm wondering if it may be beneficial or malevolent to do so.

Comment: My point was that you can test it (and there are definitely tools you can use to analyze performance differences that a human wouldn't notice at small scale). Maybe you won't be able to tell the difference, in which case it doesn't really matter. But maybe you will. And that is a better answer for you than someone here suggesting whether you should or shouldn't based on who knows what.

Comment: Yes, I got your point, but I disagree with what is a better answer.

Comment: Then maybe you should phrase your question better. Do you care about performance or do you care about something else? If something else, what specifically?

Comment: My question did not mention, or even imply, in my mind, performance. I'm more interested in: will adding a Prepare() on subsequent loops cause it to become unstable.

Comment: The title made it unclear to me at least. Hurt, help or make no difference is not exactly specific and typically implies a performance concern. Really sorry if you don't see it that way. *shrug*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sufficient to call cmd.Prepare() once. It doesn't care about the parameter values, just the parameter sizes. Calling it multiple times won't cause problems, but it's not necessary either.